# How to validate several forms in one view using single view model in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a view with single view model called `DataViewModel`.

In this view I have more than one form. Now I can't set all properties to required because if I do so then if I click for example Save button which saves certain fields. There are some other fields that are not required for the save button but required for add button. How can I handle validation in this case?

Also, If I have an error in one action which is one form and I used `return View();` it will show all errors of required fields that I actually don't need for this specific action. And If I used `RedirectToAction()`, then the page is returned with no error even if there were one.

DataViewModel

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string personName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string classChosen { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string className { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ClassCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string newPersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Index view

```
@model DataViewModel

<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddPerson" method="post">
    <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control scan" placeholder="New Person" 
    asp-for="newPersonName " />
    <span asp-validation-for="newPersonName " class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="model-close button btn btn-primary primary-btn" 
    style="width:auto;" value="Add" />
                                   
 </form>
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
       \\Here I'm adding person with class data
</form>
```

Home controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddPerson(DataViewModel model)
{
    Person person = new Person();

    if (model.newPersonName != null)
    {
        person.Name = model.newPersonName;
        person.status = true;

        var personName = dbContext.Person
                                  .Where(w => w.Name == model.newPersonName)
                                  .Select(w => w.Name)
                                  .FirstOrDefault();

        if (personName == null)
        {
            personRepository.AddPerson(person);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("newPersonName", "Name already exists");
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("newPersonName", "Please enter valid value");

    return View("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(DataViewModel model)
{
    // Code for adding classes for person
    return View(model);
}
```

How can I handle such a case?

Because when I click add for adding new person with return view it shows all errors even ones that are not related to adding new person. and same for same. How can I separate the validation for several forms in one view using single view model

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to only use client side validation,If the data is not required,the form data will not be passed to the action:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public string personName { get; set; }
    public string classChosen { get; set; }
    public string className { get; set; }
    public string ClassCode { get; set; }
    public string newPersonName { get; set; }
}
```

Index view:

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AddPerson" method="post">
    <input required="required" type="text" class="form-control scan" placeholder="New Person" 
    asp-for="newPersonName " />
    <span asp-validation-for="newPersonName " class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="model-close button btn btn-primary primary-btn" 
    style="width:auto;" value="Add" />
                                   
 </form>
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" method="post">
       input required="required" type="text" class="form-control scan" placeholder="New Person" 
    asp-for="className " />
    <span asp-validation-for="className " class="text-danger"></span>
    <input type="submit" class="model-close button btn btn-primary primary-btn" 
    style="width:auto;" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want it from server side. I fixed the issue by using partial view and each is having it's own view model and in the main one I'm not returning the model. I return the view with the model and it works fine. So, now it validated from both sides server and client.